# C# / JavaScript local code in hosted web apps on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, uwp, hosted-app

We have a fully functional website. Now we want to develop a windows 10 app and since hosted web apps seem the quickest way we want to explore that option. I have created hosted web app for our site but can I embed any local code in the app that can communicate with code website. Like can I change the user agent string to recognize request is from hosted web app? Can I access camera from local code? I was unable to find any resources on these. Or do I have to use a webview in UWP app and load website in it? Any suggestions?

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Have you read [help/on-topic]?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/hwa-access-features#call-windows-runtime-apis) first. If your url is defined within the app’s bounds(ACURs), then you can call windows runtime api which can help you acess to camera. But I didn't find any windows runtime API which can help you change your user agent.